# How to retrieve data point into edit text from matlab workspace to gui?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, text, edit

I have 8x1 cell matrix in my matlab workspace called textdata. It contains tickers in each row. How do I use pushbutton and `edit1_Callbacks` to program a this basic data point retrieval operaton (what is the code and where do I type it? No fancy stuff, just want to know how to import the textdata into gui and with the push of a buttun retrieve the first ticker into the edit text box (1 data point from first row of textdata)?

Comment: You should start to accept given answers in order to get new ones.

Comment: OK thanks for the tip...didnt know. Can u help me with this basic question?

Comment: What have you done so far? Try to post a minimal prototype that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: if (isempty(input))
     set(hObject,'String','Ticker1')
end
guidata(hObject, handles);
But iam not sure it can read Ticker1 because i have not imported the contents from workspace... help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Matlab function [`evalin`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/evalin.html) to retrieve a workspace variable from your GUI.

The following example GUI demonstrates this, you can probably expand from this starting point:

```
% GUI
function so_wsgui
figure('units','normalized',...
    'position',[0.15 0.15 0.7 0.7],...
    'color',[1 1 1]*0.5,...
    'numbertitle','off',...
    'menubar','none',...
    'toolbar','none',...
    'tag','figure');
data=guihandles(gcf);
uicontrol('parent',data.figure,...
    'style','pushbutton',...
    'string','Import',...
    'units','normalized',...
    'position',[0.1 0.85 0.8 0.05],...
    'callback',@import_callback);
uicontrol('parent',data.figure,...
    'style','edit',...
    'horizontalalignment','center',...
    'backgroundcolor',[1 1 1],...
    'units','normalized',...
    'position',[0.1 0.5 0.8 0.05],...
    'tag','text');
data=guihandles(gcf);
guidata(gcf,data);
end
% Callbacks
function import_callback(obj,event) %#ok
data=guidata(gcbf);
try
    wsvar=evalin('base','textdata');
    set(data.text,'string',wsvar{1});
catch exception
    set(data.text,'string',['Error: ' exception.identifier]);
end
end
```

However you have to be careful with this because nothing garantees you that the variable exists or that it is a cell array, so you must be cautious. This is not really the usual way to pass data to a GUI.